# Philadelphia Sitecore User Group: SitecoreUML & Experience Request Routing (XRR)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

- **Date/Time (local):** Tuesday, 14 November 2017 *at 6:00pm*
- **Date/Time (UTC):** Tuesday, 14 November 2017 *at 11:00pm*
- **Location:** Delphic Digital, 10 Shurs Ln, STE 201, Philadelphia, PA 19127
- **Event Details:** [Meetup Details and RSVP](https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-User-Group-Philadelphia/events/244899519/)
- **Contact:** @zachary_kniebel (Sitecore Community Slack)
- **Description:** The Philadelphia Sitecore User Group is pleased to announce a fantastic group of speakers for this meetup. First, we have Joe Bissol, Ryan Capple and Mahesh Patil of Comcast presenting on Experience Request Routing (XRR)! After that, Zachary Kniebel of EPAM Systems will be introducing his latest tool, SitecoreUML! Join us for whats's sure the be an informative evening! As always, refreshments will be provided!